# Trying Select Distinct in Proc Sql statement for a specific column

Tags: sas, distinct, proc-sql

I want to use `select distinct` in a `proc sql` statement for a specific column. I have around 10 columns, and I don't want to check the duplication for the whole 10 columns, I just want to check the duplication for one column.

So when I write the `proc sql` like below, `select distinct` checks the duplication through the all 10 columns:

```
proc sql;
     create table newtable as
        select distinct Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4, ... , Col10 from oldtable;
quit;
```

I tried to write something like below to check the duplication for only Col3, and adding other columns too into the new table. But it failed. I also tried different combinations like adding a new `select distinct Col3` after the `from oldtable`, but all combinations failed. So what is the trick?

```
proc sql;
     create table newtable as
        select (distinct Col3), * from oldtable;
quit;
```

Answer (score 3):

That's not how `select distinct` works: it can only select distinct values from the entire return clause.

It's unclear what you mean by 'check duplication'.  Assuming SAS finds a duplicate on one of the rows of your particular column, which row is it supposed to pick?

The easiest way to do this, if you don't particularly care which row comes back, is to use `proc sort nodupkey`.  SQL doesn't actually do this very well, particularly the ANSI 1999 version SAS uses; you can `group by` the main variable and use `max` or `min` or similar for *all* of the other variables, but that doesn't necessarily give you a single real row.

If you do want a single real row, `union` does have automatic deduplication in it; so you can use it like this.  Selecting `where 0` means nothing gets selected, but allows us to use `union`.

```
data class_Extra;
  set sashelp.class;
  output;
  if _n_=5 then output;
run;

proc sql;
  create table class_nodup as
    select * from class_extra where 0
    union
    select * from class_extra;
quit;
```

But a better solution: fix the original problem that created the duplicate.

Comment: The problem is that I got "duplication" from a previous Left Join process, which means that the input table was like 1000 rows, and the output table was like 1100 rows. I was expecting the output table as 1000 rows too, but obviously some rows saved two times after the left join (That's why I call it duplication).

I just wanted to remove the repeating rows in the next step depending on only one column.

Comment: Sounds like you need to fix the left join process then.

Comment: and I tried to implement `select distinct` in the previous step, in the Left Join process, but it didn't work. 

But I will check `group by`, if it can help me in the LEft Join process

Comment: More likely, you have duplication in your data on the right side of your left join.  Fix that.

Comment: I want to keep the size (row numbers) of the Table_a, so I think Table_a should be in the right side of the join, right? Like `Table_b left join Table_a`

Comment: If table_a has duplicates, then you still will get extra rows.  Otherwise how does SQL know which of the duplicates you want?